# Cannot get datas from mysql using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to get datas from mysql database using sequelize and then i want to store that datas in one variable,how to do that ?

I already tried using query, but i want to do that using sequelize.

```
 var quisms = function(req, res) {
     Quicksms.findAll().then(function(data) {
             res.status(200).json(data)
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
             res.status(500).json(error)
         });

 };
```

Comment: Consider sharing your part of code.

Comment: please edit your question.

Comment: i want to get datas from Quicksms table

Comment: How are you defining you Sequelize tables?  How are you loading Sequelize into that file you are making the query from?